# Dynamic Button in UItableViewCell IOS/Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

[Button in tableViewcell programatically with AutoLayout in raw and column wise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjIj0.png)

How to create Dynamic Button in tableViewcell programatically  Using Swift Language with AutoLayout in raw and column wise.

thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I already try to do this but my button canot be pressed, it's the cell wich was selected. So i think it's a bad idea because when you select a cell you select all the cell and not a part of this cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegate for UITableViewCell and call it under button action.